# AngularJS not parsing curly braces properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```html
<li ng-repeat="appliance in appliances | limitTo:2">
  <div class="icon">
    <img src="images/vector/Appliances/w-{{appliance.DashboardIcon}}.svg">
  </div>
  <div class="label">{{ appliance.Label }}</div>
</li>
```

In AngularJS I can see in the console that it tries to load '/images/vector/Appliances/w-%7B%7Bappliance.DashboardIcon%7D%7D.svg'. Now my ng-repeat works just fine. If I decodeURIComponent I see that the above %7B and %7D are '{' and '}' respectively. How can I prevent this error from happening?

Comment: Use `ng-src` directive

Comment: `src="images/vector/Appliances/w-{{appliance.DashboardIcon}}.svg"` here `{{appliance.DashboardIcon}}` is part of string and hence it is not parsed.

Comment: Thank you so much, you were spot on vidriduch

Comment: I already tried the first answer :)

Answer (score 4):

`Use ng-src` here instead `src`

```
 <img ng-src="images/vector/Appliances/w-{{appliance.DashboardIcon}}.svg">
```

> Using Angular markup like {{hash}} in a src attribute doesn't work
>   right: The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text
>   {{hash}} until Angular replaces the expression inside {{hash}}. The
>   ngSrc directive solves this problem.

The buggy way to write it:

```
<img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{hash}}" alt="Description"/>
```

The correct way to write it:

```
<img ng-src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{hash}}" alt="Description" />\\
```

For more info see this link https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `ng-src`, if you use src, the browser tries to load the image before angular's loaded, that's why ng-src exists.

```
<img ng-src="images/vector/Appliances/w-{{appliance.DashboardIcon}}.svg">
```